# Convert File to Blob in Dart Flutter

Tags: file, flutter, dart, blob

```
File sampleImage;
  Future getImage() async {
    var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      sampleImage = tempImage;
    });
  }

void submitValues(){
Blob blob = new Blob(sampleImage);
}
```

I need to convert the File into Blob in flutter in order to save in the database, I can't find any reference to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after further investigation i figured it out

```
void submitValues() async {


Blob blob = new Blob(await sampleImage.readAsBytes());
}
```

await needs to be added along with readAsBytes in order to convert the File type variable into Blob