# how to convert a file to blob in flutter without importing dart:html cuz it can't run on android

Tags: flutter, file, dart, blob

how to convert a file to blob in flutter without importing dart:html cuz it can't run on android
Error: Not found: 'dart:html'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62015474/convert-file-to-blob-in-dart-flutter